# Shape of signals in PORTB of PIC after executing code

Tags: microcontroller, pic, port

I am trying to understand how in this document the signals in PORTB.0, PORTB.1 and PORTB.2 are drawn.
[image: signals of PORTB in pic]
According to the code, there is an infinite loop and we are every time adding 10 (in binary), so when we add 10 at the beginning we get 10, I think that is why only PORTB.1 is at 1, then when we add another 10 we get 100 so the PORTB.2 gets a 1, and then we get 110 so both PORTB.1 and PORTB.2 are at 1.Is my thinking right? And if it is right why when PORTB.1 is at 1 in 2 cycles why PORTB.2 is at four cycles?

Comment: B1 is high after one loop and B2 is high after 2 loops. Two dashed boxes represent one loop as drawn.

Comment: `PORTB.2` and `PORTB.1` form a 2 bit counter that counts 00, 01, 10, 11, 00, 01, etc. etc. ... it overflows into the higher bits, if there are any in PORTB

Comment: Thank you very much, but why two dashed boxes represent one loop ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you ask. You need to look at the surrounding text, which might define the time per "box" (division). _We_ don't know the definition. Who drew the blue traces, you?

Comment: The blue traces is the solution of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Quoting, extending, and formatting your "thinking":

1. We start with PORTB.1 and PORTB.2 at 0,

> 2. so when we add 10 at the beginning we get 10, I think that is why only PORTB.1 is at 1,
> 3. then when we add another 10 we get 100 so the PORTB.2 gets a 1, [and PORTB.1 gets a 0]
> 4. and then we get 110 so both PORTB.1 and PORTB.2 are at 1.
>    5. And then we get 1000 so both PORTB.1 and PORTB.2 are at 0 again. For PORTB.1 and PORTB.2 this is the same as state 1.

Let's look at the 4 different states.

| State | PORTB.1 | PORTB.2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

> Is my thinking right?

Yes, it is. On the observed pins this is a 2-bit counter going through the well-known sequence.

> And if it is right why when PORTB.1 is at 1 in 2 cycles why PORTB.2 is at four cycles ?

PORTB.2 has the doubled number of cycles because its significance is doubled. Remember, this is a digital counter using 2 as its number base.

> Why two dashed boxes represent one loop?

Since we have no information about the unit per box, we can just guess. You forgot to reference "the document."

It might be a time step, but we do not know the system clock.

It might be a reminder that PORTB.0 is static at 0, and one of the other tasks of the same document presented a counter toggling PORTB.0 once a box.

Anyway, the complete loop takes 6 system clocks, assumed you have a PIC16. So a box is equivalent to 3 system clocks.